# Github commit with different user

Tags: git, github, commit, git-commit

I have a github account. When I make commits it shows a different user than my github account username. How can I fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the root of your local folder you have a file named "config".
Try to "vim .git/config"

The file will look something like that:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        fileMode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://nanhe@bitbucket.org/nanhekumar/myproject.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master`

    [user]
            name = Nanhe Kumar
            email = info@nanhekumar.com
```

A few options:

1. Change the user name and email in this file
2. Use "git config" command to change a global user for pushing to github or a local user for a specific folder project:

Local:

- git config --local user.name ""
- git config --local user.email "< your email>"

Global:

- git config --global user.name ""
- git config --global user.email "< your email>"